# Trying to add rounded corners to a photo

Tags: html, rounded-corners

I am trying to add rounded corners to an image, but it does not seem to take effect when I do.  I am not sure if I am putting the border-radius in the right location.  Would someone be able to offer any advice by chance?

```
<p style="margin-bottom:0px">
    <a href="Unpublisthed Website" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="Unpublished Photo"  alt="Photo" width="124" style="max-width:124px; height:auto; border:0 border-radius:20px">
        <br><br></a>
    <span  style="FONT-SIZE: 7pt; line-height: .8">&nbsp;Click picture to view<br></span>
    <span  style="FONT-SIZE: 7pt; line-height: 1.6">&nbsp;introduction video.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: You forgot a `;` after `border:0`

Comment: Voting to close as the issue is caused by a typo.